# copying all .txt files from the CWD to another directory in perl

Tags: perl

There are 5 .txt files in my current working directory that I want to transfer to another directory in perl but it is not working. Here is my code:

```
my $current_dir = Cwd::cwd();

my $dest_dir = "Path_to_destination";

system("/bin/cp \"$current_dir\/*.txt\" \"$dest_dir\"");
```

For some reason, I get this error message:

```
/bin/cp: cannot state `Path to current working directory/*.txt': no such file or directory.
```

Can anyone please help? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: **Hint:** Use `File::Copy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify that:

```
system("/bin/cp *.txt $dest_dir");
```

Or just use [`File::Copy`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Copy;

... 

copy($_, $dest_dir) or die "Can't copy $_: $!" for <*.txt>;
```

Comment: @user2812535 If it helped, you can accept the answer by clicking on the check mark next to the answer. Please read [accepting an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more details.